# handling RecyclerView OnClickListener in Activity/Fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When migrating from `ListView` to `RecyclerView` handling "onItemClick" seems to become painful.

One of the two most popular approaches is making your `ViewHolder` implement `View.OnClickListener` and handle `onClick` there. [Here](https://gist.github.com/grantland/cd70814fe4ac369e3e92) is an example of this approach.

What is the good practice to fire this "onClick" back from item's `ViewHolder` to the Fragment/Activity hosting the `RecycleView` and handle it there ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As you said there are a few approaches and the implementation depends on the design of the rest of code, what the logic and how modulor you want the objects to be.

- Add onItemClickListener to the entire holder can be found
  [here](http://sapandiwakar.in/recycler-view-item-click-handler/) and
  its a nice way to do it if you have only a click at the entire item. Notice: if you are going to implement swipe2dismiss with it then it will cause you some pain because of the touch events and multiple *TouchEventListener*
- Let your fragment implement *OnClickListener* and pass it to the
  adapter and then pass it to the holder so it will get the onClick
  events of the views in the holder that you want, then create
  switch-case at the fragment to handle it.

IMO: the best practice is to pass OnClickListeners because then when you want to use that view in a different class and want a different click handling it will be easier to implement.

Comment: So, passing `onClickListener` to viewHolder is the best practice ? I wonder about potential issues given that you have multiple `viewHolder`s, each of them holding reference to the Fragment ?

Comment: Each one is pointing to the same location in memory. Plus, ther eis noy way (unless u did something extraordinary) that the holder will alive longer then the fragment so there is no issue with memory leaks.

Comment: +1. I agree. It would be great to have code snapshots in your answer, mainly for further readers to benefit from them, what do you say ?

Comment: No prob but in a few days :)

Answer (score 1):

This code really works for me. Put it in your Activity class in the `oncreate()` method.

```
final GestureDetector mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(MainActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

});

recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());


        if (child != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The Item Clicked is: " + recyclerView.getChildPosition(child), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // below code get the position of data
            int a=recyclerView.getChildPosition(child);


            return true;

        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a onclicklistener inside viewholder,and implement it in activity
here is the demo:
https://github.com/yefengfreedom/YfRecyclerView

and the code below:

```
/**
 * click recycler view item
 *
 * @param <T> t
 */
public interface OnItemClickListener<T> {
    void onItemClick(View view, T t);
}
```

.........

```
public void setOnItemClickListener(RecyclerViewInterface.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
    mOnItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}
```